# MIPS number conversion

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

MIPS Assembly Language program which runs interactively to convert between decimal, binary, and hexadecimal.

1. Request input data type.
2. Request input data.
3. Request output data type.
4. Output the data. Use any algorithm

This is the requirement of my homework and I have written the below code , let me know why it drops off while running.

This is the code I have please let me know why it doesn't work properly.

```
#Provide data variable and data as an input and output
.Data
Input1: .asciiz "Kindly enter the input X:"
Input2: .asciiz "Please provide the number system Y details:"
Output: .asciiz "\nThe result will be R:"

#starts global main
.Globl Main
main:
addi $A0, $zero, 2
addi $A1, $zero, 15

#get the input value dropped by the user
getX:

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Input1
syscall
li $M0, 5
syscall
blt $M0, $zero, getX

move $K0, $M0

#get the value of the number system dropped by the user
getY:

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Input2
syscall
li $M0, 5
syscall
blt $M0, $A0, getY
bgt $M0, $A1, getY

add $K1, $zero, $M0

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Output
syscall

add $N0, $zero, $K0
add $N1, $zero, $K1

jal convert

li $M0, 15
syscall

#perform conversion over the respective input and number system
convert:
addi $sp, $sp, -16

sw $A3, 12($sp)

#Applying counter that is used to check that how many
#times values will be popped up from the stack
sw $A0, 8($sp)
sw $A1, 4($sp)
sw $ra, 0($sp)

add $A0, $zero, $N0
add $A1, $zero, $N1

beqz $A0, end

div $K4, $A0, $A1
rem $K3, $A0, $A1
add $sp, $sp, -4
sw $K3, 0($sp)

add $N0, $zero, $K4
add $N1, $zero, $A1
addi $A3, $A3, 1

jal convert

end:

lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $A1, 4($sp)
lw $A0, 8($sp)
lw $A3, 12($sp)
beqz $A3, done
lw $N0, 16($sp)
li $M0, 1
syscall

#operation performed
done:
addi $sp, $sp, 20
jr $ra
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "drops off"?  What happens when you run it for different inputs?  copy/paste actual input and output ([mcve]), and show what you found using MARS's built-in debugger to single-step execution.

Comment: What's with those weird register names? I assume `$M0` is supposed to be `$v0`, `$N0` is supposed to be `$a0`, etc? After the call to `convert` it looks like you're trying to execute system call 15, which in MARS is `write_to_file`. That seems a bit odd. Did you mean to use system call 10 (`exit`)?

Comment: It is missing a `.text` directive, and sadly the failure mode for that is no error, no nothing.  So, this code isn't even assembling.